# zlib-1.2.11 configuration options

Tags: linux, gcc, zlib

When Compiling zlib from source-

```
./configure --help
```

show configuration options without any information so I'm wondering what

```
--const and --zprefix
```

is used for. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that zlib 1.2.11 fails to build if --zprefix is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--const` turns on the use of the `const` keyword for input arrays to zlib functions. This is not the default as it breaks older code. For new code, the compile-time checking offered by the use of `const` is a benefit.

`--zprefix` precedes all external symbols with `z_`, to reduce the probability of a symbol name collision in a large application. So you would call `z_crc32()` instead of `crc32()`.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: `--zprefix` has some hidden documentation in zconf.h: `/*
 * If you *really* need a unique prefix for all types and library functions,
 * compile with -DZ_PREFIX. The "standard" zlib should be compiled without it.
 * Even better than compiling with -DZ_PREFIX would be to use configure to set
 * this permanently in zconf.h using "./configure --zprefix".
 */`

Comment: `--const` is not documented.